# IIS7 and permanent redirects using the location tag in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis-7, web-config

I need to setup some 301 permanent redirects in the web.config of an ASP.NET application running under IIS7.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="services.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="default.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
  <location path="products.htm">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="default.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

All the pages I redirect from will redirect to the home page - is there a quicker and/or easier way of doing this as I have over 10 pages I need to redirect to default.aspx? I can specify a location section for each of the 10 pages but had hoped for a more concise approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could set .htm to be handled by the ASP.NET library (the same as .aspx is by default), and then look at the requests in Application_BeginRequest in your global.ascx, redirecting when appropriate.

It's a bit more involved than one or two redirects in a Web.config, but after a certain amount it becomes easier.

Comment: If the .htm/.aspx file does not exist on the file system, Application_BeginRequest in the global.ascx wont get triggered.

Comment: It will if you don't select "check file exists" on IIS5/6 or something like "Invoke handler only if request is mapped to file" on IIS7 (can't recall exact wordings, but I've used beginrequest for URIs that don't map to files, dozens of times).

Comment: can this be setup in the web.config?

Comment: Closest thing I can think of to that that is defined in a web.config is to set a handler for a path, but then the handler has to deal with passing through those .html files that match the path selection but you don't want redirected.
Maybe there's a way to set extensions to be handled by asp.net through web.config I don't know about though, I've just always done it through IIS.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to entering your pages one-by-one into web.config is to create an `HttpModule`. With IIS7+ in Integrated mode, by default `HttpModules` will run for all content, including static files.

To do the redirect in code, call `HttpResponse.RedirectPermanent(string url, bool endResponse)` in an early event. For best performance, set endResponse = true.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the IIS URL Rewrite module.

It's an official module that you can download here:
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

This module is like a swiss army knife for all URL redirection or rewriting needs.